# Redirect to new page on button onclick in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have many buttons inside of webpage like this.

```
<div class="btn btn-sm btn-success mycustom_btn"  onClick="javascript:clickinner();">more</div>
<div class="btn btn-sm btn-success mycustom_btn1"  onClick="javascript:clickinner();">more</div>
<div class="btn btn-sm btn-success mycustom_btn2"  onClick="javascript:clickinner();">more</div>
```

What i am trying to do is call  function clickinner() on button onclick event. I tried to grab the button element by class name and change the target url.
The javascript code is as follows.

```
<script>
function clickinner(){
    var mybtn=document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
    mybtn.onClick="location.href='about-us.html'";
};
</script>
```

I don'twant to grab the element by Id so that i have to assign unique id each time. However whenever i click on any of buttons, the target link is not working.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clicked button can be accessed by using `this` in the `clickinner` function, no need to get it by class name:

```
<div class="btn btn-sm btn-success mycustom_btn"  onClick="javascript:clickinner(this);">more</div>
<div class="btn btn-sm btn-success mycustom_btn1"  onClick="javascript:clickinner(this);">more</div>
<div class="btn btn-sm btn-success mycustom_btn2"  onClick="javascript:clickinner(this);">more</div>
```

Furthermore, you can just directly redirect to the 'about-us' page, since you're already in the click event. So ...

```
<script>
function clickinner(target) { // Target refers to the clicked element
    location.href='about-us.html';
};
</script>
```

... is enough.

If you need to go to different pages based on which class the button has, you can do something like:

```
function clickinner(target) {
    if(target.classList.contains('mycustom_btn')) {
        location.href = 'another-page.html';
    } else {
        location.href='about-us.html';
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `this` as parameter to your function and change the location correctly

```
<div class="btn btn-sm btn-success mycustom_btn"  onClick="javascript:clickinner(this);">more</div>
<div class="btn btn-sm btn-success mycustom_btn1"  onClick="javascript:clickinner(this);">more</div>
<div class="btn btn-sm btn-success mycustom_btn2"  onClick="javascript:clickinner(this);">more</div>


<script>
    function clickinner(mybtn){
       // Do your stuff here with the clicked button
       location.href='about-us.html';
    };
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/asv548g2/

Answer (score 0):

Working [fiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/codeepic/L26tb1rL/4/)

HTML:

```
<div id="button">more</div>
<div class="btn btn-sm btn-success mycustom_btn">more</div>
<div class="btn btn-sm btn-success mycustom_btn">more</div>
<div class="btn btn-sm btn-success mycustom_btn">more</div>
```

JS:

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert('only 1 button clicked');
    window.location = 'about-us.html';
});


var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        alert('each button clicked');
        window.location = 'about-us.html';
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>First Page</title>
 <script>
  function clickinner() {
    window.location.href = 'secondPage.html';
    }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="btn btn-sm btn-success mycustom_btn"
    onClick="javascript:clickinner()">more</div>
<div class="btn btn-sm btn-success mycustom_btn1"
    onClick="javascript:clickinner();">more</div>
<div class="btn btn-sm btn-success mycustom_btn2"
    onClick="javascript:clickinner();">more</div>

 </body>
 </html>
```